# Setar a cor de uma div com base em um objeto recebido por props

Tags: javascript, array, react

Como eu faço para setar a cor de uma div com base em em um objeto recebido por props?

**Map feito no arquivo App:**

```
<div className={styles.grid}>
    {levels.map((item,key) => (
       <GridItem key={key} item={item}/>
    ))}
 </div>
```

**Objeto recebido:**

```
    const levels = [
    { title: 'Magreza', color: '#96A3AB', icon: 'down', imc: [0, 18.5] },
    { title: 'Normal', color: '#0EAD69', icon: 'up', imc: [18.6, 25]},
    { title: 'Sobrepeso', color: '#E2B039', icon: 'down', imc: [25, 30]},
    { title: 'Obesidade', color: '#C3423F', icon: 'down', imc: [30, 99]},
];

export default levels;
```

**Index do GridItem:**

```
import levels from "../../helpers/levels";
import styles from "./GridItem.module.css";
import upImage from "../../assets/up.png";
import downImage from "../../assets/down.png";




const GridItem = (levels) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.main} style={{ backgroundColor: levels.color }}>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default GridItem;
```

Estou fazendo o passo a passo de um projeto do curso b7web, porém o professor usou Typescript e recebeu por props um type, como faço para produzir o msm efeito sem typescript, recebendo por props a cor contida no objeto "levels"?

Answer (score 0):

Arquivo APP, linha: `<GridItem key={key} item={item}/>`
Você está passando a variável `item` para dentro do componente `GridItem`, ou seja vc está passando um objeto igualzinho a esse `{ title: 'Magreza', color: '#96A3AB', icon: 'down', imc: [0, 18.5] }` para cada item do array `levels`. Está correto.

Agora no arquivo GridItem você tem que recuperar esse objeto e é aqui que está o seu erro:
`const GridItem = (levels)`

Você deve recuperar a variável `props` no lugar de `levels`. E dai dentro de `props` vc consegue acessar cada item assim: `props.item`, e assim por diante vc consegue acessar cada propriedade do objeto item.

Fiz um [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ramanujan-clphwb?file=/src/GridItem.jsx) caso fique com dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo(a).